# generate an output csv containing the unique rows of an input csv where column1 and column5 values are duplicated

Tags: bash, csv, awk, duplicates

I want to write a bash command (also pure python can be accepted - no pandas, numpy, etc) which takes in input a csv, let's say input.csv, select the rows where the tuples of the values of column1 and column5 are duplicated, and saves them into another csv, let's say output.csv.
Then from this list, removes the duplicated rows (rows having the same tuples of the values of all the columns)

Just to be clear, ***the condition*** to add a row to the output csv is:

```
IF 
    the current row (row1) value of col1 is equal to the value of col1 of a row already parsed  (row2)
    AND
    the current row (row1) value of col5 is equal to the value of col5 of the already-parsed row I am considering (row2) 

        IF row1 is not already in output.csv:
            THEN 
            add row1 in output.csv       

        if row2 is not already in output.csv:
            THEN 
            add row2 in output.csv
```

### Some info on the data

- The data in these csv is not sorted. The output does not have to be sorted.
- The columns are separated by semicolon `;`
- All the values of Col1 and col5 have the same length.
- the data comes from a postgresql DB table in which the column where defined as:

  ```
  col1 TEXT,          -- only digits, all values have the same length 

  col2 TEXT,          -- only digits, all values have the same length        
  col3 TEXT,          -- only digits, all values have the same length        
  col4 TEXT,          -- only digits, all values have the same length  

  col5 TEXT,          -- only digits, all values have the same length        

  col6 TEXT,          -- dates: yyyy-mm-dd, digits and dashes "-", all values have the same length 
  col7 TEXT,          -- dates: yyyy-mm-dd, digits and dashes "-", all values have the same length
  col8 NUMERIC,       -- digits and sometimes point: i.e. 1.99, 4.8, 30
  col9 SMALLINT,      -- only digits, all values have the same length
  ```

### What I have, what I want

So let's suppose that my input.csv is something like:

(The first column are the line indexes, but they are not in the csv, it is just for clarity on this question)

```
    col1 ...  col5 ... col9

1   10   ...  01   ... 1001
2   10   ...  02   ... 1002 
3   10   ...  03   ... 1003 
4   11   ...  04   ... 1004 
5   11   ...  03   ... 1005 
6   11   ...  04   ... 1001 
7   10   ...  01   ... 1001 
8   12   ...  05   ... 1003 
9   12   ...  05   ... 1004 
10  10   ...  01   ... 1001
```

It does not matter what is in the other columns, and the csv has 9 columns.

I want my output.csv to be

```
col1 ...  col5 ... col9
 
11   ...  04   ... 1004 
11   ...  04   ... 1001 
10   ...  01   ... 1001
12   ...  05   ... 1003
12   ...  05   ... 1004
```

<sup>The output order does not matter</sup>

example 2:

If in the input.csv there are these two rows:

`1 a a a 1 a a a a`

`1 b b b 1 b b b b`

Both must appear in the output.csv

### What I tried

I have tried to build such a command with awk.

1. First trial:

I know for sure that if I had to generate a list of records where just the values of col1 are duplicated, I could run this

```
awk -F';' 'NR==FNR{count[$1]++; next} count[$1]>1 && !visited[$1]++' input.csv input.csv >> output.csv
```

So based on this command, I have tryed with

```
awk -F';' 'NR==FNR{count[$1]++; next} count[$1]>1 && !visited[$1]++ && NR==FNR{count[$5]++; next} count[$5]>1 && !visited[$5]++' input.csv input.csv >> output.csv
```

but it looks like it does not work.

2. Second trial:

I guess "the rows where both the value in column1 and column5 are duplicated" is equivalent to say "the rows where the concatenated values of column1 and column5 are duplicated".

So, based on this assumption, I have tryed with

```
# concatenate valuesm of col 1 and 5 in col 10
awk -F ';' '{ $NF = $1 $5 } 1' OFS=';' input.csv input.csv >> output_10.csv

# extract unique list of rows where the col10 is duplicate
awk -F';' 'NR==FNR{count[$10]++; next} count[$10]>1 && !visited[$10]++' input_10.csv input_10.csv >> output_duplicated_10.csv

# remove the 10th column
awk 'BEGIN {FS = OFS = ";"} {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if (i != 10) printf "%s%s", $i, (i==NF?ORS:OFS)}' {{ output_duplicated_10.csv >> output_duplicated.csv
```

but it does not work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The order does not matter

Comment: you need to give some examples for  `...`. The meaning of "unique rows" is unclear. What if two rows are `1 a a a 1 a a a a` and `1 b b b 1 b b b b`. Your samples imply only one line is output so how do you choose between `a` and `b` ?

Comment: This might help: `awk 'NR==1{ print; next } { rows[$1$5]=$0; counter[$1$5]++ } END{ for(i in rows) if(counter[i]==2) print rows[i] }' file.csv`

Comment: "the rows where both the value in column1 and column5 are duplicated" is only equivalent to "the rows where the concatenated values of column1 and column5 are duplicated" if the width of all values in each column is constant. Otherwise `a bc` and `ab c` both concatenate to `abc`.

Comment: You don't say what data the CSV can contain, but your `awk` approach would fail, if a CSV field contains a newline or the field separator itself (`;`).

Comment: @jhnc the couple (10,03) appears only one time in the csv, so it has no duplicates, and then must not appear in output

Comment: @jhnc thanks, I did not noticed that. Maybe that was actually the first error I made when I started writing the code to do the operation.

Comment: FYI we idiomatically name the array `seen[]` when used as you're using `visited[]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say this would work for just column 1:

```
awk -F';' '
    NR==FNR{count[$1]++; next}
    count[$1]>1 && !visited[$1]++
' input.csv input.csv >> output.csv
```

You say testing concatenated columns would work.

So, just replace occurrences of column 1 values (`$1`) with the new key:

```
awk -F';' '
    {k = $1 FS $5}
    NR==FNR{count[k]++; next}
    count[k]>1 && !visited[k]++
' input.csv input.csv >> output.csv
```

It looks like you need to read a tutorial on `awk` to understand the pattern/action format and also how linebreaks are interpreted. When you concatenate two programs with an `&&` in between them, the result is not to run both programs and then "and" the results of each part together.

To copy the header to the output, add a test for line 1:

```
awk -F';' '
    {k = $1 FS $5}
    NR==FNR{count[k]++; next}
    count[k]>1 && !visited[k]++ || FNR==1
' input.csv input.csv >> output.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

If your input is

```
col1,col2,col3
11,00,04
10,13,01
10,13,01
13,20,01
11,01,04
23,20,07
```

you could use [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/6.8.0/installing-miller/) and run

```
mlr --csv count-similar -g col1,col3 \
then filter '$count>1' \
then cut -x -f count input.csv
```

to get all the rows in which (in my sample file) col1 e col3 values are duplicated

```
col1,col2,col3
11,00,04
11,01,04
10,13,01
10,13,01
```

To filter this output and obtain only unique values, you can add `uniq` verb and run

```
mlr --csv count-similar -g col1,col3 \
then filter '$count>1' \
then uniq -a \
then cut -x -f count input.csv
```

to get

```
col1,col2,col3
11,00,04
11,01,04
10,13,01
```

If you want to extract only the first row in which you have a duplicate for col1 and col3, you can run

```
mlr --csv cat -n \
then count-similar -g col1,col3 \
then filter '$count>1' \
then sort -f n \
then head -n 1 -g col1,col3 \
then cut -x -f n,count input.csv
```

to get

```
col1,col2,col3
11,00,04
10,13,01
```

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot intall any new component on the machine where I have to accomplish the task, bu thanks for the answer!

Comment: @Tms91 a curiosity: what was the way I proposed that was most suitable for you?

Comment: the first method.